# Getting MySQL syntax error on function case and VARCHAR

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, db2

I am getting some SQL syntax error when i try to run a simple MySQL function create queries . These are working on Db2 . i want to run it on MySQL .

```
CREATE FUNCTION SAMPLE1
  (
    I INTEGER
  ) RETURNS VARCHAR(4)
  BEGIN
    CASE
      WHEN I < 256 THEN RETURN CAST(SUBSTR(HEX(I), 1, 2) AS VARCHAR(4));
      WHEN I > 255 AND I < 4096 THEN RETURN CAST((SUBSTR(HEX(BITAND((I / 256), 255)), 2, 1) || SUBSTR(HEX(BITAND(I, 255)), 1, 2)) AS VARCHAR(4));
      ELSE
        RETURN CAST((SUBSTR(HEX(BITAND((I / 256), 255)), 1, 2) || SUBSTR(HEX(BITAND(I, 255)), 1, 2)) AS VARCHAR(4));
    END CASE;
  END;
```

and after running on mysql , i am getting error like

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(4));
      WHEN I > 255 AND I < 4096 THEN RETURN CAST((SUBSTR(HEX(BITAND' at line 11
```

and next

```
  CREATE FUNCTION SAMPLE2
  (
    PREFIX VARCHAR(43),
    IP4 BIGINT,
    VERSION INTEGER
  ) RETURNS VARCHAR(39)
  BEGIN
    RETURN UPPER(PREFIX ||
      (CASE WHEN VERSION = 4 THEN
                      CAST (BITAND(((IP4 + 4294967296) / 16777216), 255) AS VARCHAR(3)) || '.' ||
                      CAST (BITAND(((IP4 + 2147483648) / 65536), 255) AS VARCHAR(3)) || '.' ||
                      CAST (BITAND(((IP4 + 2147483648) / 256), 255) AS VARCHAR(3)) || '.' ||
                      CAST (BITAND((IP4 + 2147483648), 255) AS VARCHAR(3))
      ELSE
                      SUPERHEX(BITAND(((IP4 + 4294967296) / 65536), 65535)) || ':' ||
                      SUPERHEX(BITAND(IP4, 65535))
      END));
  END;
```

and getting error

```
you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(3)) || '.' ||
                      CAST (BITAND(((IP4 + 2147483648) / 65536), 255) AS ' at line 14
```

and the last query

```
CREATE FUNCTION SAMPLE3
  (
    CONNECTED TIMESTAMP,
    DISCONNECTED TIMESTAMP,
    INTERVAL BIGINT
  ) RETURNS INTEGER
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  CONTAINS SQL
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    IF (CONNECTED IS NULL) THEN
        RETURN -1;
    ELSEIF (DISCONNECTED IS NULL) THEN
        RETURN CASE WHEN (INTERVAL = 0 OR CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES > CURRENT TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    ELSE
        RETURN CASE WHEN (INTERVAL = 0 OR CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES > CURRENT TIMESTAMP) AND CONNECTED > DISCONNECTED THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    END IF;
  END;
```

getting error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERVAL BIGINT
  ) RETURNS INTEGER
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  CONTA' at line 9
```

1. Is `VARCHAR` not used in mysql `CAST` function ?
2. INTERVAL `BIGINT`, `CALLED ON NULL INPUT` and `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END` is different in mysql queries ?

Any suggestion or solution ?

Comment: So, did you "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax" to create functions?

Answer (score 1):

The types used/accepted by MySQL's CAST are fairly general. Try replacing all your `CAST(.... AS VARCHAR(X))` with `CAST(... AS CHAR)`. If you need to force a precise type, you can assign the cast results to declared variables.

Edit: Just tested a little further; `CAST(... AS CHAR(X))` works too; it is the VAR part of the cast MySQL apparently does not like.

Comment: also what is the problem in the 3rd query line `RETURN CASE WHEN (INTERVAL = 0 OR CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES > CURRENT TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;` ?

Comment: I have edited VCHAR(3) to CHAR(3) in 2nd query . so `CAST (BITAND(((IP4 + 4294967296) / 16777216), 255) AS CHAR(3)) || '.' ||` and getting error `right syntax to use near 'CHAR(3)) || '.' ||`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but INTERVAL is a reserved word, so using it could cause weird issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not like this

"WHEN I < 256 THEN RETURN CAST(SUBSTR(HEX(I), 1, 2) AS VARCHAR(4))"

It's like this

WHEN I < 256 THEN RETURN CAST(SUBSTR(HEX(I), 1, 2) AS VARCHAR(4)

Comment: what is the problem in the 3rd query  line `RETURN CASE WHEN (INTERVAL = 0 OR CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES > CURRENT TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;' ?